# Xamarin MSAL Azure AD B2C Login shows browser instead of web view

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently using Xamarin/MSAL with Azure AD B2C.

It works without a problem.

However, when the login method is invoked it shows the browser instead of web view, which has address bar displaying URL. According to documentation it should display web view (both client and server flows)?

To invoke login im using this code:

```cs
 AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), UIBehavior.ForceLogin, "ui_locales=sv", App.UiParent);
```

Is there any way to force web view instead of browser?

Comment: What platform are you seeing this behavior on? (PC, Android, iOS)

Comment: Im seeing this on Android and iOS. I've done some reasearch apparently new version of MSAL changed to invoke Chrome instead of web view, which is the reason why url bar is show. There is no way to remove it sadly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have discovered, you can't force the login request to an embedded user agent, but there is a good reason for this.

The observed behavior is consistent with the [IETF's Best Current Practice for OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.txt) that:

"... the best current practice is to perform the OAuth authorization request in an external user agent (typically the browser) rather than an embedded user agent (such as one implemented with web-views)."

It further says:

"Encouraging users to enter credentials in an embedded user-agent without the usual address bar and visible certificate validation features that browsers have makes it impossible for the user to know if they are signing in to the legitimate site; even when they are, it trains them that it's OK to enter credentials without validating the site first."

Authorization servers, such as Google, block OAuth authorization requests in an embedded user agent "for all OAuth clients on platforms where viable alternatives exist".

Comment: on the other hand, there are Android phone makers who don't install chrome / chrome tabs, and therefore Xamarin.Android applications that use MSAL.Net won't work on these

Answer (score 3):

From what I see right now MSAL supports Embedded webviews as follows:

```
await App.AuthenticationClient
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(GlobalConstants.AzureB2C.Scopes)
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.UIParent)
                    .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Where `WithUseEmbeddedWebView`accepts a boolean

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Xamarin Android in MSAL can only launch Chrome or Chrome Custom Tabs. We are currently working on including embedded webview support in MSAL.

Comment: Embedded webview will be optional (the detault will still be to use system web view, as recommended by the best practices. The embedded web view will be a fallback.